# Display inline-block elements won't vertically aligned

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically align the two boxes inside the container but it not seems to work.

```css
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.suggested-box {
    width: 40%;
    height: 80%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px #000;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <section class="suggested-box"></section>
  <section class="suggested-box"></section>
</section>
```

I searched around similar questions but didn't find any helpful answer.

Comment: Try providing a live example (with actual CSS instead of SASS).

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? I was assuming that you wanted the middles of the two suggested-box elements to line up with each other, but they are the same size and they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add line-height to your container

```
.container{
    // size(width, height)
    @include size(97%, 250px);
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 250px; //line-height equal the height
}
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/zhouxiaoping/gok4r2tr/